# How to make a user input a number, the pick that item from a current list and add it to a new list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im making a quick snap game for fun, just learning to code, and I can’t seem to get around this problem.

```
set1 = ["Horse", "Cow", "Pig", "Goat", "Chicken", "Sheep", "Donkey", "Duck", "Rabbit"]
set2 = ["Horse", "Cow", "Pig", "Goat", "Chicken", "Sheep", "Donkey", "Duck", "Rabbit"]
random.shuffle(set1,random.random)
random.shuffle(set2,random.random)
side1 = int(input("What number would you like to pick from side one?"))
side2 = int(input("What number would you like to pick from side two?"))
s1pick = set1.index(side1)
s2pick = set2.index(side2)
picks = []
```

I want them to input 2 numbers for `side1` and `side2`, then store what the corresponding values from `set1` and `set2` are in `s2pick` and `s1pick`. But I keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/nice memes/src/snap.py", line 26, in <module>
        s1pick = set1.index(side1)
ValueError: 4 is not in list
```

Using python 3 on pycharm community edition. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean `set1[side1]` instead `set1.index(side1)`, you want index 4 not value 4

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) returns the *index* of the element value you pass it to. So for a list `l = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, `l.index('b')` would return `1`.

If you want to go the other direction, getting a value for an index, then you should use the item access syntax:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l[1]
'b'
```

So in your case, you want to use `set1[side1]` in order to get the value that the user chose from `set1`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot. I should of probably know this but i havent used python since i used it in class a few months ago.

Comment: I would use `set1[side1-1]`, so you don't have to think about starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

`index()` [actually returns the index of the value that you pass to the method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html). You're getting an error because the value `4` isn't in the list that you're calling the `index()` method on. If you're already turning the prompt into an `int()` after getting it from the user, then you can just specify that you'd want the element at that index from the list like this:

```
s1pick = set1[side1]
s2pick = set2[side2]
```

Be careful, though. The `input()` that you get could be out of range of your lists. So, I would would put your inputs into a while loop to make sure that you get a valid input:

```
side1 = # input code
side2 = # input code

while side1 not in range(len(set1)) or side2 not in range(len(set2)):
    side1 = # input code
    side2 = # input code
```

Comment: I was planning on going back and stoping the code from breaking like that, but i was going to use Exception handlers, which would be better?

Answer (score 0):

comparing the two pieces code:

```
list1 = ["Horse", "Cow", "Pig", "Goat", "Chicken", "Sheep", "Donkey", "Duck", "Rabbit"]
list2 = ["Horse", "Cow", "Pig", "Goat", "Chicken", "Sheep", "Donkey", "Duck", "Sheep"]

######################
index1 = 2
index2 = 3
element1 = list1[index1]
element2 = list2[index2]
print (element1) # output: Pig
print (element2) # output: Goat


######################
index1 = list1.index("Sheep")
index2 = list2.index("Donkey")
print (index1)   # output: 5
print (index2)   # output: 6
```